# JS: Why this code isn´t changing when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm testing an example from the book "JavaScript the definite guide" (Flanagan, O' Reilly).

And can't understand two things:

1. why you add [0] at the end of this line: `var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];`
2. Why isn't working?

**[I've pasted the code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rosamunda/q8AQn/1/).**

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="reveal">
    <h1 class="handle">Click here!</h1>
    <p>Parrafo escondido!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.reveal *{display:none;}
.reveal *.handle {display:block; color:red;}
```

**JS**

```
//esperamos a que el doc cargue completamente
window.onload = function() {
    //buscar todos los elementos con la clase 'reveal'
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal");
    //para cada uno..
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elt = elements[i];
        //buscamos en cada elemento encontrado la clase 'handle'
        var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];
        //revelar el resto del contenido cuando el elemento es clickeado
        title.onclick = function() {
            if(elt.className == "reveal") elt.className = "revealed";
            else if(elt.className == "revealed") elt.className = "reveal";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what about your code isn't working?  are you checking for errors in the console?  doing any logging?

Comment: Works fine when you adjust the loading position of the code http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q8AQn/3/ (you had on window.onload within another)

Comment: I want to translate that book, in the near future.

Comment: Among many things, you *might* want to take a look at Douglas Crockford's "Javascript the Good Parts". That's just my opinion but it may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer of your question: *why you add [0] at the end of this line*

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), it returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names.

So, We need to use index to fetch the elements. thus `[0]` is added the get the first element with class

SEE [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8AQn/4/), Your code works, use no wrap

Comment: Thanks!! For both answers! So, my lack of knowledge about how JSFiddle works was the culprit, but it wasn´t anything wrong with the code. Found more information about it -just in case anyone else wonders- in here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

There is a `[0]` at the end of

```
var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];
```

because the `getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of all the elements in the document, and so to access the first element of an array you use a subscript (`[]`) accessing the first element.

The reason `getElementsByClassName` returns an array as opposed to `getElementById` is because `id`'s are unique and so there is only one, but a class is allowed (and indeed *will*) be used many times and so an array of each element using that class is returned instead.

As for the code, it is indeed correct but on your JSFiddle you had selected onload and you had already wrapped the code in an `onload` function. To remedy this you could either remove the `window.onload` wrapper or you could change how the script is loaded in the JSFiddle to `No wrap in -<head>`. Obviously, removing the `window.onload` wrapper will mean that the code will fail in a normal website as the DOM will not be loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function addEvent(elt){
        //buscamos en cada elemento encontrado la clase 'handle'
        var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];
        //revelar el resto del contenido cuando el elemento es clickeado
        title.onclick = function() {
            if(elt.className == "reveal") elt.className = "revealed";
            else if(elt.className == "revealed") elt.className = "reveal";
        }
}

window.onload = function(){
//esperamos a que el doc cargue completamente
    //buscar todos los elementos con la clase 'reveal'
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal");
    //para cada uno..
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        addEvent(elements[i]);
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q8AQn/5/

Answer (score 0):

Though not sure what you want to achieve by the code but still answer to your first question is that - 
document.getElementsByClassName or document.getElementByName or any other document (dot) function.... returns an Array so to access first element on array you need to add [0].